# How to download a typeface from a website's code if this typeface is protected?

Tags: google-chrome, fonts, typography

I just read this question on Stack Overflow stackoverflow.com/questions/20711393/how-do-i-download-extract-font-from-chrome-developers-tools/20711425#20711425 but I didn't arrived to download the typeface as the answers say.

I want to download the New Transport typeface from one of these sites and I don't reach my goal. Is it possible or impossible?

http://www.newtransport.co.uk/
http://fontdeck.com/typeface/newtransport

Thank you for your attention :-)

Comment: I would like to precise that I'm a student and I can't afford to pay 100 pounds for a typeface but I have to use this one. It's only for an investigation project, not for commercial use nor anything else. Thank you for your help!

Comment: What do you mean "have to"? If someone told you to use it, they are responsible for making sure you have access to it.

Comment: It's me who has chosen to make it with that typeface. I made some experiences with the first version, the Transport, but there's this new one, New Transport which is apparently inaccessible and I'd like to use it because my work consists in making a mix between San Francisco (the latest Apple typeface) and Transport (the typeface used on UK's roads). The thing is the if there's a new release of transport, I should use it because it's supposed to be better than the first one. And I would like to use it for this study. Do you have any idea? Thanks : - )

Comment: Then the only real answer is "that's too bad?". If you can't afford its license, look for a font that you *can* afford (because it's free, like [Raleway](https://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Raleway), or has a "free for personal/educational" license). I have no idea why you "should" use the new version if the old one works, but here's a thought: [contact the people](http://www.a2-type.co.uk/html/contact.html) who [make it](http://www.a2-type.co.uk/html/New_Transport_Chaumont_Poster.html) and ask them for permission to use it, instead of asking on stackoverflow how to violate copyright law ;)

Comment: Hi Mike, thank you for your answer! :-) I totally agree with you, I just sent them an email few days ago but I don't have any answer yet. I think it's a clever way to do it. I completely agree with you, I'll try again. Thank you and have an amazing day! :-) < 3